# Windows Authentication not working for localhost address in IIS 7.5

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

I have hosted my website on local IIS server 7.5 and configured Windows Authentication. When I try  to access the url with the hostname, it asks username and password through Windows Security form whereas when I access the url with the localhost, it doesn't asking username and password.

Can any help me to go through?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows Authentication not working on local IIS 7.5. Error 401.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466665/windows-authentication-not-working-on-local-iis-7-5-error-401-1)

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Internet Explorer and typing your user name and password in manually will allow you to log in, you can just add the site's hostname into your intranet zone.

Otherwise you may be running into the loopback check issue. This can be resolved by adding the hostname into a registry key and restarting the IIS Admin service.

You can find the details of how to do this here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861

The article says IIS 5.1 and above but the steps are still relevant.

Comment: Link is dead :(

Comment: @VictorWilson This answer is missing bits, please try here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466665/windows-authentication-not-working-on-local-iis-7-5-error-401-1